# What are the most defensive types in Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

My Pokemon team, at the moment, has a lot of offensive heroes, but lacks quite a bit in defense. So, which types are the most defensive? (which types have the most immunities/resistances)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer: Steel Pokemon have the most resistances, and high defensive stats too. Many pokemon have only 1 weakness, but [Eelektross](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eelektross_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) has zero due to its ability, and can be aquired in Pokemon Sun and Moon using the [Island Scan](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/dailyevent.shtml) on Poni Island on Sunday.

Full answer in terms of both Monotype and Dual-Type pokemon, and looking at Abilities as well.

First Monotype pokemon

Types with the most Resistances and Immunities

- Steel: 11
- Fire: 6
- Poison: 5
- Poison with Levitate Ability: 6 (Weezing)

Types with the fewest Weaknesses

- Normal: 1 (Fighting)
- Electric: 1 (Ground)
- Electric with Levitate Ability: 0 (Eelektross)
- Water with Lightning Rod Ability: 1 (Grass weakness, Hidden Ability Seaking)

Types with most Net defenses (Resistances and Immunities minus Weaknesses)

- Steel: 8
- Fire: 3
- Poison: 3
- Poison with Levitate Ability: 5 (Weezing)
- Water with Lightning Rod Ability: 4 (Hidden Ability Seaking)

There are a significant number of dual-type combinations, so this list will be less exhaustive. Below are notable Dual Types with particularly few Weaknesses, or many Resistances. Note that most dual steel types have many resistances.

- Dark/Ghost - 4 Resistances/Immunities, 1 Weakness (Spiritomb and Sableye)
- Dark/Poison - 5 Resistances/Immunities, 1 Weakness (Alolan Muk, Skuntank,  Drapion)
- Water/Ground- 5 Resistances/Immunities, 1 Weakness (Swampert, Seismitoad, Gastrodon (has 1 more resistance with Storm Drain Ability)
- Steel/Bug - 9 Resistances/Immunities, 1 Weakness (Forretress, Genesect)
- Electric/Water with Levitate - 6 Resistances/Immunities, 1 Weakness (Rotom Wash)
- Electric/Fire with Levitate - 9 Resistances/Immunities, 2 Weaknesses (Rotom Heat)
- Steel/Ghost - 12 Resistances/Immunities, 4 Weaknesses (Aegislash)

Special Mention of Shedinja, due to Wonder Guard granting it 13 immunities, and only 5 weaknesses

Comment: I would like to add Empoleon to the list with 10 resistances and 1 immunity. 3 weaknesses.. 1 of them is Ground which he can take care of with any of his water attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the best defensive Pokémon by type.

Type combinations with the least amount of weaknesses:

- Normal(61 Pokémon) e.g. Snorlax or Regigigas
- Electric (27 Pokémon) e.g. Normal Raichu or Electabuzz
- Normal/Ghost (0 Pokémon) Nonexisting
- Water/Ground (10 Pokémon) e.g. (Mega) Swampert or  Gastrodon
- Poison/Dark (3 Pokémon) e.g.  Skuntank or Drapion
- Bug/Steel (7 Pokémon) e.g. Forretress or Genesect
- Ghost/Dark (3 Pokémon) e.g. (Mega) Sableye or Spiritomb

Comment: The way I understand it, the question is about which type has the most resistances/immunities and least weaknesses. It's not asking which Pokémon has the highest defense stats.

Comment: Ah, Fair. Either way. Its something that can be found rather quickly with a quick google. Pokemondb.net has a huge page full of Effectiveness charts. Including the Type Combinations with the least Weaknesses.